# phpcassa usual query methods or cql queries?

Tags: cassandra, cql, phpcassa

Can you recommend what methods of queries to choose?Cql or usual classes?
Phpcassa has both methods.cql is more comfortable than usual.but what will be efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the evidence is that CQL is as fast or faster than the older RPC-based API.  (See comments on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2500, for example.)